# In Typescript what does a type annotation with two types between two curly braces mean?

Tags: typescript

An example:

```
function doSomething(): { string, SomeClass } {
 ...
}
```

From playing around with the compiler it seems that it will accept any return value that is an object with any number of `string` keys and `SomeClass` values.

So something like this:

```
{
 "key1": someClass1,
 "key2": someClass2,
  ...
}
```

Is my understanding correct?

--Update--

It seems like the annotation I need is `{ [key: string]: SomeClass }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope - that function signature means 'this function will return an object that has the keys `string` and `SomeClass`, and `any` values'. This means that this will compile fine:

```
function doSomething(): { string, SomeClass } {
  return {
    string: false,
    SomeClass: 1
  }
}
```

It's functionally equivalent to:

```
function doSomething(): { string: any, SomeClass: any }
```

Answer (score 5):

To see what it really means, you can check it with code like this:

```
let a: { string, SomeClass };

let v: void = a;
```

The compiler will tell you:

```
Type '{ string: any; SomeClass: any; }' is not assignable to type 'void'.
```

So, `string` and `SomeClass` in this case are not types at all, they are property names, and their type is inferred as `any`. Turning on `--noImplicitAny` usually helps to clarify that.

Answer (score 3):

```
function doSomething(): { string, SomeClass } {
 ...
}
```

It actually means:

```
function doSomething(): { string: any, SomeClass:any } {
 ...
}
```

And can be extracted for clarity to:

```
interface YourReturnType{
    string: any;
    SomeClass: any;
}

function doSomething(): YourReturnType {
 ...
}
```

If you want to return an object that has an arbitrary number of `SomeClass` you need to use an *index signature*.

```
interface YourReturnType{
  [key: string]: SomeClass
}
```

However, keep in mind that you will only be able to define other properties in this returned type of type `SomeClass`.

To avoid this kind of confusion, I recommend you turn on the compiler option `noImplicitAny` which won't let you compile code like the one you have originally posted.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a function which return an object like you describe, you should do the following thing:

```
function doSomething(): { [key: string]: someClass } {
   // Do your stuff
}
```

In the case `someClasse` has a unknown type, you can do something like that:

```
function doSomething(): { [key: string]: any } {
   // Do your stuff
}
```

I hope that will help you, have a nice day